# Facebook updates posted to wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I am trying to set up a page on a wordpress site that displays the feed for a facebook fan page. I can't seem to locate the RSS link and it seems tons of people are having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Facebook doesn't have RSS feeds for fan pages at the moment. You could use a tool like feed43 to create an RSS feed. here's a tutorial on how to use it: http://feed43.com/step-by-step.html

Answer (score 1):

I know that Facebook does not have an official RSS for statusupdates, however if you are a programmer then fetching the data and output in rss format shouldn't be to hard. However I do not konw if Facebook allow this so you would have to look that up first. I'll break up the problem in parts for you.

1. Getting page with the statusupdates you want to gather, possibly requering some sort if authenication if it's not a public profile. Not sure on how Facebook works there but something like that.
2. Pasing the data finding theinformation you want (status updates).
3. Outputting the array of statusupdates in a suitable way for you project. I guess you want a sidebar widget in wordpress from the content of your question but outputting it as an rss or whatever shouldn't be hard either. This is probably the easiest part.